# Use vue components on react.js (vuera plugin)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I use a wrapper component or use the HOC API: all error
[enter link description here][1]

> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on
>   'Document': The tag name provided
>   ('/static/media/Button.b2f16a92.vue') is not a valid name.

Am I missing any plugins

Comment: please care to add the code here instead of images

Comment: Can you post the code, so that we don't guess what you tried?